# How do I create a cron job via a chef receipe using the cron resource?

Tags: chef-infra

I have the following in the `cron.rb` file.

```
cookbook 'cron', '~> 7.0.4', :supermarket

cron 'Check-In to Chef Manage' do
   minute '*/2'
   command 'chef-client'
 end
```

I've verified that the recipe is on the node, via Chef Manage, and yet it doesn't run on the node.

I don't understand if anything else needs to be configured.

Comment: Do you know if the cron job was created on the node? What's the output of `crontab -l` from `root` user (assuming chef-client runs as root).

Comment: I checked, it isn't created on the node. That is the issue I am having. I don't understand what is wrong with the recipe above. Because it is uploaded to the chef infra server. Shows up in the cookbook that is in the runlist. And I manually went to the server and ran "chef-client" to apply the cookbook's recipe.

Comment: You're better off using the cron_d resource than the cron resource and dropping files into /etc/cron.d

Comment: @seshadri_c turns out I don't need the first line. And second, the issue was that the cron recipe was not called in the default.rb file. I am new to chef and didn't realize this was a requirement.

Comment: @lamont I'll consider this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line is not needed. Leaving the recipe (i.e. cron.rb) as:

```
cron 'Check-In to Chef Manage' do
   minute '*/2'
   command 'chef-client'
 end
```

Second, cron.rb must be called in the default.rb file; i.e. `include_recipe "<cookbook nam>::cron"`